# Посоветуйте хорошую книгу по алгоритмизации

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Посоветуйте хорошую книгу по алгоритмизации.

Answer (score 3):

[Кормен](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/), творение Максима Иванова [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/), разборы на сайте [TopCoder](http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/Algorithm+Problem+Set+Analysis).
Существует, еще достаточное множество источников, но это скорее всего мои фавориты.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю Кормен действительно самое лучшее, если знания позволяют можно попробовать почитать [Кнута](http://www.ozon.ru/?context=search&group=div_book&text=%c4%ee%ed%e0%eb%fc%e4+%dd.+%ca%ed%f3%f2&catalog=1008).

Answer (score 0):

Мне [Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке. Автор: Стивен Скиена](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6290126/) понравилась. Недавно в БиблиоГлобус-е на Лубянке видел.

А Кнут это неувядаемая классика (читать обязательно).

Comment: Вспомнил шутку:

-Вычитали Кнута?

-Нет, но на полке он стоит

Comment: Да, "от корки до корки" это редко... 

Сам когда-то прочел много в 1-м и особенно в 3-м, а 2-й том скорее просматривал.